# Returning characters before varying character in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of data in excel that looks like this (credit ratings)...

[image]

Is there a way to pull just the letter portion of each rating with a formula in excel?

The ideal outcome would be this the following...

[image: BB BB CCC B BB B CCC CCC CCC]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the line of using the `TEXTBEFORE()` function:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A13,{"-","+","*"}),A1:A13)
```

---

Or, Not needed `REDUCE()`, but posted initially,

```
=REDUCE(A1:A13,{"+","*","-"},LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y,)))
```

---

Or, Just `TEXTSPLIT()`

```
=TEXTSPLIT(A1:A13,{"-","+","*"})
```

---